# Creating recovery database in Exchange 2016 fails

Tags: exchange

I just built a new server using Windows Server 2016 and Exchange Server 2016. I'm trying to salvage an old mailbox from SBS 2011. I have the directories containing the old EDB file and all the log files. I'm following the directions on [this page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29986.exchange-troubleshooting-recover-mailbox-from-edb-file-with-free-built-in-tools.aspx). However, when I get to the step of creating the recovery database from the old EDB file, it tells me I gave an invalid path to the log files. Well, the path I gave it has more than 5,000, 1KB log files, so I don't know what it's complaining about. In fact, one of the previous steps pointed to the same folder with no problems (eseutil /r E00 /l "S:\ExchangeOLD\Mailbox" /d "S:\ExchangeOLD\Mailbox Database"). Any thoughts as to how I can get past this step? Here's the command and resulting error from the Exchange Management Shell (which I ran As Administrator).

```
New-MailboxDatabase -Server Moe -Name "RecoveryDB01" -Recovery -EdbFilePath "S:\ExchangeOLD\Mailbox Database\Mailbox Database.edb" -LogFolderPath "S:\ExchangeOLD\Mailbox"
The location that you specified for the transaction log files is invalid. Verify that the directory exists and that there are no files in it.
Parameter name: LogFolderPath
    + CategoryInfo         : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-MailboxDatabase], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=MOE,RequestId=eb653ed6-9bd7-4a94-a17e-52cbce7bd8d7,TimeStamp=2/19/2018 7:41:22 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ArgumentException] D7BCE79C,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.System
  ConfigurationTasks.NewMailboxDatabase
    + PSComputerName       : moe.birdus.local
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't recover a prior version Exchange mailbox database.

Comment: @joeqwerty All I really need to do is get my mailbox out of the old database and stick it in the new database. Is that doable? Especially without buying 3rd party software, as this is just a one-off task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@joeqwerty is right. You can't mount a SBS 2011 (Exchange 2010) DB to Exchange 2016. You can't even use a recovery mailbox database on a different AD forest / schema.

There are some ways to extract a .PST file or mailbox from a edb-database-file (like [free veeam version](https://www.veeam.com/microsoft-exchange-recovery.html), [edb to pst](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c9676a39-a36e-4db2-a3cf-c968f2013806/free-privedb-to-pst-tool?forum=exchangesvr3rdpartyappslegacy)), but let me tell you: It should be easier, or at least not much more difficult, to just install SBS2011/Exchange 2010 on another server or VM, mount the database and either migrate the mentioned mailbox over to your new Exchange 2016 installation, or export the mailbox from there.

Comment: Actually tried mounting the database back on the old system hard drive, but ran into issues. Ended up installing Veeam and exporting the mailbox to a PST (free!). Piece of cake! Imported that into 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the location in which no log file is present, as log file needed to make the database in Clean State, which already done. So just provide the folder path with no log files details.

Answer (score 0):

To mount SBS 2011 (Exchange 2010) database on Exchange server 2016, use following steps:

**1.** Prepare Exchange Server 2016:

**a.** Exchange server 2016 should run same or later version of Exchange server 2010 Service Pack as the SBS 2011 server.

**b.** Make sure that all required Exchange server roles are installed on Exchange Server 2016.

**c.** Exchange server 2016 should have same accepted domains as the SBS 2011 server.

**2.** Prepare the SBS 2011 Server

**a.** Check that database is in a clean shutdown state using Eseutil/MH command if database is in dirty shutdown then first you need to recover it. Refer this Microsoft link: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/repairing-exchange-databases-with-eseutil-when-and-how/ba-p/610276

**b.** Take full backup of database & logs.

**3.** Copy database and logs on Exchange server 2016

**4.** [Mount the Exchange database on the Exchange 2016 Server](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/171138-how-to-mount-exchange-2010-database-on-exchange-2016)

**5.** Open  Exchange Admin Center & check database is mounted & all mailboxes are accessible.